How to use slice LUTs only as logic?
This is part of utilization report after synthesis,
1. Slice Logic
--------------

+----------------------------+------+-------+-----------+-------+
|          Site Type         | Used | Fixed | Available | Util% |
+----------------------------+------+-------+-----------+-------+
| Slice LUTs*                |  554 |     0 |    101400 |  0.55 |
|   LUT as Logic             |  553 |     0 |    101400 |  0.55 |
|   LUT as Memory            |    1 |     0 |     35000 | <0.01 |
|     LUT as Distributed RAM |    0 |     0 |           |       |
|     LUT as Shift Register  |    1 |     0 |           |       |
| Slice Registers            |  633 |     0 |    202800 |  0.31 |
|   Register as Flip Flop    |  633 |     0 |    202800 |  0.31 |
|   Register as Latch        |    0 |     0 |    202800 |  0.00 |
| F7 Muxes                   |    0 |     0 |     50700 |  0.00 |
| F8 Muxes                   |    0 |     0 |     25350 |  0.00 |
+----------------------------+------+-------+-----------+-------+

I want to compare slice register cost between different strategies. So LUT as memory should be banned. I already know adding these codes
attribute ram_style : string;
attribute ram_style of myram : signal is "distributed";

in vhdl could avoid LUT as RAM, however, LUT as shift register still exists.
Any reference for this is very welcome.
Update:
Much thanks for the two comments. I was using Vivado 2019.1.1 for synthesis. Thanks for the comment explaining the principle of LUT as memory. However, I still have no idea how to deliberately avoid this.
Update:
One solution is adding
attribute srl_style : string;
attribute srl_style of my_srl : signal is "register";

in vhdl, which is the second way mentioned in the answer. Thank you!

What synthesis tool are you using?

Using "distributed" style will force synthesis to use LE FFs as RAM, avoiding block RAM. "LUT as memory" is a different thing: here the combinatorial part of the LE is used as storage (so the LUT output is fed back to an input, and the table is loaded with an expression like out = (set or current) and (not reset).


LUT as shift register still exists. ... I still have no idea how to deliberately avoid this.


Use the output from all stages of the shift register as inputs to other logic or connect them to top-level outputs.

or

Use placement directives to make sure the shift register flip-flops are assigned to slice registers rather than LUTs

Even using the output of one intermediate flip-flop or assigning one intermediate flip-flop to a slice register might be enough to break up the shift register so that it isn't possible to place it in a LUT.
Sorry I don't know enough Vivado to know if there's a simple directive that just tells it not to create SR's in LUT's.
